# iOS add view to Button in IB

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I am trying to add a view on a `UIButton` inside IB. The only problem it doesn't allow me to put in inside the button only on top?

Is this not possible through IB or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in Interface Builder. You have to add it in code.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this:

> **Do Not Customize Controls by Embedding Subviews**
>
> Although it is technically possible to add subviews to the standard system controls—objects that inherit from UIControl—you should never customize them in this way. Controls that support customizations do so through explicit and well-documented interfaces in the control class itself. For example, the UIButton class contains methods for setting the title and background images for the button. Using the defined customization points means that your code will always work correctly. Circumventing these methods, by embedding a custom image view or label inside the button, might cause your application to behave incorrectly now or at some point in the future if the button’s implementation changes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW26

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a UIView on your UIButton you can achieve it in 2 different ways

1. The easy way is to follow Cyrille answer: you can do it programmatically because IB doesn't allow you to modify a UIBUtton adding a view on it
2. The hard way is to create your custom button (let me call it "MYCustomButton"), that extends a UIButton, and use it in your application. With this way when you need to modify the buttons in your interface, you can achieve it modifying the XIB of the "MYCustomButton".